# EntityRef or EntitySet in one to one relations?

Tags: linq, silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

What should I use for a one-to-one relation? According to [this](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database-SQL-CE--Association-attribute) I should use `EntitySet`, but it seems illogic to me since I don't want a collection but a single item.

Is there any good examples for one-to-one relations?

Edit: changed the link, I had made a mistake